# How to use Scrapy Items and store output in json format?

Tags: python, json, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to get my output to look like the following in json format.

```
[{"title": "Test", "kategorie": "abc", "url": "www.url.com"},
{"title": "Test", "kategorie": "xyz", "url": "www.url.com"},
{"title": "Test", "kategorie": "sca", "url": "www.url.com"}]
```

but after using Items I see some of the values but not all of them are stored in a list:

```
[{"title": ["Test"], "kategorie": ["abc"], "url": "www.url.com"},
{"title": ["Test"], "kategorie": ["xyz"], "url": "www.url.com"},
{"title": ["Test"], "kategorie": ["sca"], "url": "www.url.com"}]
```

This is my items.py

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    kategorie = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

This is my pipelines.py which is enabled in settings.py.

```
class MyPipeline(object):

    file = None

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('item.json', 'wb')
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

This is the parse method in my spider.py. All xpath-methods return a list of scraped values. After it they are put together and iteratively create a dictionary that will end up in the exported file as json.

```
def parse(self, response):

   item = MyItem()

   title = response.xpath('//h5/text()').getall()
   kategorie = response.xpath('//span[@class="abc1"]//text()').getall()
   url = response.xpath('//div[@class="abc3"]//a/@href').getall()

   data = zip(title, kategorie, url)

   for i in data:
      item['title'] = i[0],
      item['kategorie'] = i[1],
      item['url'] = i[2]

      yield item
```

This is how I start the crawling process:

```
scrapy crawl spider_name
```

If I don't use Items and Pipelines it works fine using:

```
scrapy crawl spider_name -o item.json
```

I am wondering why some of the values are stored in a list and some other are not. If someone has an approach it would be really great.

Comment: Without the actual html of the page, it is difficult to know what the xpath selectors return. Also your pipeline is really not required. Just use [`FEEDS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds) setting instead. Finally instead of zipping and yielding each item from the zip object, just yield individual items from the response object. Note that `xpath...getall()` returns a list while `xpath...get()` returns a string

Comment: All three xpath commands return a list of comma separated strings like ["first string", "second string", "third string, ...]. I am relatively new to Scrapy. Could you please provide a short code snipped how the yield statement is used? I am also not sure where to implement Feeds and which values I should assign to.

Comment: What link are you trying to scrape?

Comment: https://brownfield24.com/grundstuecke

Comment: These are the commands:

url_ = response.xpath('//div[@class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-small uk-card-default uk-box-shadow-small"]//a/@href').getall()

title = response.xpath('//h5/text()').getall()

kategorie = response.xpath('//span[@class="uk-text-bolder"]//text()').getall()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using scrapy `FEEDS` and `Item` you can directly yield the item objects from the parse method without the need for `pipelines` or `zip`ing the lists first. See below sample

```py
import scrapy

class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    kategorie = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sample'
    start_urls = ['https://brownfield24.com/grundstuecke']

    custom_settings = {
        "FEEDS": {
            "items.json":{
                "format": "json"
            }
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for property in response.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'uk-link-reset')]"):
            item = MyItem()
            item['title'] = property.xpath(".//h5/text()").get()
            item['url'] = property.xpath(".//a/@href").get()
            item['kategorie'] = property.xpath(".//div[@class='uk-card-body']/p/span/text()").get()

            yield item
```

Running the spider using `scrapy crawl sample` will obtain below output.

[image: Sample scrapy crawl run]